# What are Jim and Bob trying to solve?

Tags: reverse-puzzling

Jim is so happy after finding three solutions to a problem, then he texts Bob this :

> Bob, I have found 3 solutions for your problem. I do not know whether
>   these three are the only solutions or not, but I am sure there must be
>   less than 15 solutions.
>   1A,1C,2C,2E,3A,3B,4E,4F,5B,5D,6D,6F
>   1A,1C,2D,2E,3B,3F,4A,4B,5E,5F,6C,6D
>   1A,1C,2E,2F,3B,3E,4A,4B,5D,5F,6C,6D

Bob then replies:

> Thank you Jim, your solution works perfectly.

**Addition to make the puzzle clear :**

2 Days later, Jim texts Bob.

> I have found all the solutions, it has **exactly** 11 solutions,
>   but I hope you find the other solutions yourself

What are they trying to solve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is

> Planting 12 trees on a 6x6 field such that not more than 2 trees lie in the same straight line.the Apparently, the Number of solutions might turn out to be 11.

Answer (score 2):

The problem they are trying to solve is:

> How to place 12 points in a 6x6 table such that each line and each column contains exactly 2 points, and that the bottom half, the top half, the left half and the right half all contain 6 points each.

Comment: Still wrong, almost right, because the solutions must be less than 15

Comment: @JamalSenjaya I tried harder.

Comment: your last edit is still wrong, because with your problem you will find more than 15 solutions.

Comment: @KeyurPATEL Nope

Answer (score 1):

The puzzle is:

> Placing 12 points in a 6x6 table such that each row and each column contains exactly 2 points and diagonally contains 1 or 2 points.

Comment: Good start, but the problem is more complex than that.

Comment: Ok, i will try.. Thank you for a nice question..Upvote for you..